# Bash script exits after encountering "find: /data/cdr/cdr-ivr.log: No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, bash, find, exit

I am trying to write a script which accesses different servers, finds the update time of a specific file and returns the time for further processing. 
The problem is that the script exits when the file is not found on a specific server, can any one help?

```
while true
do
for i in  ocmp1 ocmp6 ocmp7 ocmp8 ocmp9 ocmp10 krrbtc krrbtd krrbte
do
ssh $i '
set -e
x=`hostname`;
echo -e "\n********************************"
echo -e "LATEST $x CDR: ";
echo -e "********************************\n"
x="tail -1 /data/cdr/cdr.log";
a=`find /data/cdr/cdr.log -maxdepth 0 -printf "%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM%TS"`;
c=`find /data/cdr/cdr-ivr.log -maxdepth 0 -printf "%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM%TS" -type d | tee log`;
b=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`;
a=${a/.*};
c=${c/.*};
SD=$(($b - $a));
```

When the file is not found and gives the following error and script exits without proceeding:

```
********************************
LATEST krrbtc CDR: 
********************************

find: /data/cdr/cdr-ivr.log: No such file or directory
bash: line 13: 20131107223022 - : syntax error: operand expected (error token is " ")
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Oh, you are using find to get the name in a different format, right. What do you see with `ls /data/cdr/cdr*` ?

Comment: What is the purpose of the second assignment to `x`? It looks like a failed attempt to extract the last line of `cdr.log`, but it doesn't appear to be used later; defunct code?

Comment: @chepner: The code shown doesn't look like it's the full script, he might be using `x` later in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using `find` when you already know the location of the file?  Why not check if the file exists, then do your work on it?

ie

```
if [[ -f "/data/cdr/cdr-ivr.log" ]]; then
  #code here
  #more code here
  ...
```

Comment: `find` is not actually used to find the file, but to print its last update time.

Comment: Sir Athos... Exactly! find is being used to get the last update time of the file. Hence i need it there nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

When the file is not found, your variable `a` is empty, causing the subtraction to fail.

You can take the `if` approach in Jason's answer, to avoid the error case, and only execute your code when the file is present.

Alternatively, if you want to always have a value, say *zero* when there is no file, you can use the bash "default value" construct. In the last line of your example, you would do this:

```
SD=$((${b:-0} - ${a:-0}));
```

This will substitute *zero* if the respective variable is null or unset, and prevent the script from dying.

In addition, you may want to ignore `find`'s error by appending `2>/dev/null` to each `find` command.